# fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP' not found in D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have install PHPMailer manually without composer and added five files in cscpl folder. I'm sending mail from gmail. But I'm getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP' not found in 
D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php:1824 Stack trace: #0 D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php(1945): 
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->getSMTPInstance() #1 D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php(1861): 
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #2 D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php(1604):
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Thu, 17 S...', 'This is a multi...') #3
D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php(1436): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #4 
D:\softwares\installed\xampp\htdocs\contact.php(91): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() 
#5 {main} thrown in D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php on line 1820
```

In the cscpl folder I have a contact.php file with following content

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    // use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


    // require_once('D:\projects\cscpl\Exception.php');
    require_once('D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php');
    require_once('D:\projects\cscpl\SMTP.php');

    $subject = "This is subject";
    $msg = "This is message";
        try{
            echo 'trying';
            $php_mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
            $php_mailer->isSMTP();
            $php_mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $php_mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
            $php_mailer->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
            $php_mailer->Port = 587;
            $php_mailer->Username = 'sender_email@gmail.com';
            $php_mailer->Password = 'sender_pwd';
            $php_mailer->setFrom('sender_email@gmail.com');
            $php_mailer->addAddress('receiver_email@gmail.com');
            $php_mailer->IsHTML(true);
            $php_mailer->Subject = $subject;
            $php_mailer->Body = 'HTML message body. <b>Gmail</b>'.$msg.' .';
            $php_mailer->send();
            echo 'done';
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo 'exp';
            /* PHPMailer exception. */
            echo $e->errorMessage();
            print_r(error_get_last());
        }
```

In the line 1824 of PHPMailer.php , it showing

```
   public function getSMTPInstance()
    {
        if (!is_object($this->smtp)) {
            $this->smtp = new SMTP();
        }

        return $this->smtp;
    }
```

And smtp.php file looks like this

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer Exception class.
 * PHP Version 5.5.
 *
 * @see       https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ The PHPMailer GitHub project
 *
 * @author    Marcus Bointon (Synchro/coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author    Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author    Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author    Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2012 - 2020 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 * @license   http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @note      This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

/**
 * PHPMailer exception handler.
 *
 * @author Marcus Bointon <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 */
class Exception extends \Exception
{
    /**
     * Prettify error message output.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function errorMessage()
    {
        return '<strong>' . htmlspecialchars($this->getMessage()) . "</strong><br />\n";
    }
}
```

I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: why have you done it without composer?  it sounds like you're missing a package, which composer would have presumably included

Comment: `not found in D:\projects\cscpl\PHPMailer.php:1824` means there is a reference there to a class which the application cannot see.  You should go to this line, see what is happening and trace it back.

Comment: Check that `SMTP.php` actually contains the expected class definition. `require_once` is a sign of an app that's not quite sure how its own dependency management works.  When you choose not to use composer, it makes a whole load of extra problems; it's *really* worth investing the time to [learn how to use it](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Comment: @jameson2012 I have a shared hosting, that's why im not using composer

Comment: in addition to what @Synchro said, if `SMTP.php` does have this class definition it's very possible that `PHPMailer` is trying to import this from some other directory as it expects the whole package to have been installed (i.e. via `composer`) so you will probably need to check and update any references

Comment: @PratikSharma - that shouldn't really be a barrier, you can do a composer install in you local environment and then push up the project with the packages to your hosting - you don't specifically need to be running composer on the hosting account

Comment: @jameson2012 ok i think that a better option.Let me give a try

Comment: Running composer locally and uploading works fine, which is why [that's suggested in the readme about how to load PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading)...

Comment: Ok, I think I better install with composer.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the file you show that's meant to be `SMTP.php` is actually the content that lives in `Exception.php`!

This is why your `require_once('D:\projects\cscpl\SMTP.php');` doesn't fail, but the subsequent attempt to create an instance of the SMTP class does.

Reinstall the files with the right names!

You really shouldn't have to touch library files at all; composer takes care of all this for you.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely write. I have same content in both the files Exception.php and smtp.php. It was my mistake.. Thank you so much , Now mail is sending.

Comment: @PratikSharma Could you please select this answer as the correct answer? Thanks.